# Greendao, creating a nonincrement (user-defined) primary key

Tags: sqlite, greendao

Is it possible in Greendao to create a non-increment **Primary Key**.
So that i can specify the value each time i insert data.
Schema is :

```
     private static void addTargetNew(Schema schema){
         Entity target = schema.addEntity("Target");
         target.addStringProperty("TARGET_ID").unique();
     }
```

Delete Query :

```
    List<Target> tList = tDao.queryBuilder().where(Properties.TARGET_ID.eq(id)).list();
    if(tList != null){
        Target t = tList.get(0);
        tDao.delete(t);
    }
```

Where datatype of id is String.

Also before, downvoting, reporting, what ever the hell problem you might be having regarding this question **PLEASE** specify the reason and give me a chance for explaination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The [documentation](http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/modelling-entities/) says:

> … entities must have a long or Long property as their primary key

Comment: ok if i change it to Long, then can i create a non incrementing (user defined) primary key ?
if YES how ?